# jQuery hide div based on input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Checking the other threads I feel like my code should work, but I must be missing something. I am trying to hide/show a div based on the input value; when the input is 1, there will be one div; when it's 2, the second div will show; if 3, third div, etc... [Here is my page](http://sokiusvente2016.org/gala-tickets/testing/).

On the page, if you select the *Individual* option, two new div's appear. Essentially only the first *please choose your meal* div will appear, and when the user changes the input to 2, the second one will appear. If the user goes back to 1, the second div should hide.

```
jQuery(function($) {
   //create div to wrap individual meal options
    $('.product-addon-please-choose-your-meal').before('<div id="individual-meals"></div>');

    //add meal choices to div
    $('.product-addon-please-choose-your-meal').appendTo('#individual-meals');
    $('.product-addon-please-choose-your-meal-2').appendTo('#individual-meals');

    //hide 2nd option if input is 2
    if ($('input[type="number"]').val() == 2) {
        $('.product-addon-please-choose-your-meal-2').hide();
    }

    //show meal options depending on user choice
    $('form').on('change', '#purchase', function(){
        // Reset required fields and hide fields
        $('select, input').prop('required', false);
        $('#table-meals, #individual-meals').hide();

        if($(this).val()=="Individual") {
            $('#individual-meals').show();
            $("#table-meals").not("#individual-meals").hide();
            $('input').prop('required',true);
            $('#table-meals select').val("Select an Option...");
        }

        if($(this).val()=="Table of 10") {
            $('input[type="number"]').val("10").prop('readonly', true);
            $("#individual-meals").not("#table-meals").hide();
            $('#table-meals').show();
            $('select').prop('required',true);
            //$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
            $('input[type="radio"].addon.addon-radio').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page is producing the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
(anonymous function) @ index:3
```

Most likely jQuery isn't loaded at all or you have code executing before it is loaded.

Comment: What do you mean? What's the incorrect script? I visited the page linked to in your question and the console showed that error.

Comment: Right, but if you click into it it's from some plugin code that's injected, not from my file.

Comment: If there's a javascript error before your code, it's not going to function properly.

Comment: **@vytfla**: The second paragraph is not clear. It"s difficult to understand what you really want and what is not working. Can you make-it more clear, please

Comment: If you look at all of the console.log messages from your code, there are repeatedly undefined values. Determine what's undefined and you'll probably resolve or at least get a clearer picture of what's causing the error. You've minified your source (including the html), which makes it hard for others to help you further.